# FFmpeg -c copy removes video for few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

If I do something like this 
`ffmpeg -i pumped.mp4 -ss 6.14  -t 0.47 -c copy  -y guiltycutshort.mp4`

then the mp4 file will be audio only. If i make the duration longer, then the first bit of the file is audio only then it goes into audio and video. I need to use -c copy because when seeking I am otherwise not getting precise accurate durations.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to use -c copy because when seeking I am otherwise not getting precise accurate durations.

Actually, the opposite is true.  When you're using `-c copy`, it isn't possible to have accurate timing.  You can't cut lossy video streams on frames, as frames aren't independent.  The only way to get the timing perfect is to decode the video and re-encode, which is not what you're doing with `-c copy`.

Additionally, it's possible that you don't have a frame on those exact timings.  If you need such accurate cutting, use frame offsets instead.

Comment: when I do use -c copy, I get the exact duration I want of 0.47 seconds but the start is like 0.012993. If I don't use -c copy, the duration is always 0.49, and if I use other unrelated mp4 videos to do the same operation, it will always be 0.04 seconds longer that I specified.

Comment: @E.SK Again, you're going sub-frame in timing, which isn't going to work.

Comment: so you're saying there is no possible way to get an exact duration like I want?

Comment: @E.SK If the frames aren't there, the frames aren't there.